# Extracting debugging information from core files

Tags: linux, automation, gdb, coredump, backtrace

I've been tasked with writing a script to clean up old core files on production Linux servers. While the script is not difficult to write, I'd like to save a basic stack backtrace to a log file before removing the core files.

Being that these servers are production, and we do not have GDB or any development tools installed, I'm looking for some quick and dirty program that will give the analog of a gdb backtrace command for a multithreaded application.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you copy the core file to another machine that *does* have gdb?

Comment: The idea is to grab and save some information about the crash before removing the core file by an automated script. That way, if looking through the logs, I could see that it appears that an application that keeps crashing is crashing in the same place, rather than losing *all* info about the crash.

Comment: Consider linking some backtracing library into the software....

Comment: We also have a program running on production Linux servers and we do have `gdb` installed on them. Why do you not consider installing gdb on the servers? Why complicate things?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things like this.  Mostly they are incomplete relative to gdb -- for example it is uncommon for backtracers to print information about function arguments or locals, but gdb can do this.  Also gdb can often unwind in cases where other unwinders choke.

Anyway, one I know of is elfutils. https://fedorahosted.org/elfutils/.  It has an unwinder in development (not sure if it is in or yet, check git).

There's also libbacktrace.  It is part of gcc and is designed for in-process unwinding.  However, it could perhaps be adapted to core files.

There's also libunwind.  I hear it is kind of terrible but YMMV.

One thing to note is that many of these require debuginfo to be available.

One last thought -- there has been a lot of work in the "catch a trace" area from the ABRT folks.  ABRT uses a kernel hook to catch a core dump while it is being made.  Then it does analysis by uploading the core to a server, files bugs, etc.  You could maybe reuse a lot of their work.  There's some other work in this space as well.

Kind of a brain dump, I hope it helps.